# Quadratic lower bound on Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, bounds

Suppose I have a multivariate Gaussian such that $p(y)=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\Sigma)$. What would be a quadratic lower bound, $f(y)$ on on $p(y)$.

i.e. for what values of k and $\Omega$ will $f(y)=-y^T\Omega y+k\le p(y)$ s.t. $p(0)=f(0)=\frac{1}{|2\pi\Sigma|^{1/2}}$

As pointed out below $k=\frac{1}{|2\pi\Sigma|^{1/2}}$

Comment: From $f(y)=-y^T\Omega y+k\le p(y)$, doesn't it follow that $f(0) = k \leq p(0)$ and so if you want $p(0) = f(0)$, then it muse be that $k = p(0)$? Why drag in an unnecessary term $k$ to confuse the issue?

Comment: There, added in your suggestion.

Comment: Using coordinates in which $\Sigma$ is the identity, you only have to solve this problem for the univariate case, where it's easy.